# Move your apps to bidding (Audience Network)

Tags: facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-ads, facebook-monetization-manager

[image]  [image]

You need to move your apps to bidding before the deadlines so they can continue monetizing with Audience Network.

after this message came to my dashboard I click (Move apps to Bidding) button and did select (No mediation platform -Audience Network only) option. As I am not using any other ad platform.

But the problem is, After doing this that notification is still on my Dashboard. Why? Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: I am also confused, If it is now bidding only why is there still an option for "No mediation platform (Audience network only)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to perform bidding it is now mandatory at least one ad must that perform bidding
you can use any platform for performing this
without bidding ads are not shows in your app.

I hope you can understand it
Thanks.

Comment: If I don't do anything else, Just Keep it this way. is it gonna do any  revenue  problem other than just showing this warning on my dashboard?

Comment: its completely impact on revenue. if you don't want to add bidding all app you need to ad at least one ad that implement bidding it is mandatory now.

Comment: its completely impact on revenue. if you don't want to add bidding all app you need to ad at least one ad that implement bidding it is mandatory now with out this zero revenue you get  for revenue need to move your apps from waterfall to bidding to monetize with Audience Network